# Receiver multiple taps

Tags: fading-channel

I would like to implement a Rayleigh fading channel for an ASK Modulation. My question is concerning the receiver. How to properly add every tap at the receiver to keep the same length from the emitter.

For instance :
Emitter : binary frame : 1*N
Channel : six taps : M*N (where M is the number of taps)
Receiver : 1*N

Thanks.

Best regards.

Comment: Are you looking for a [rake receiver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rake_receiver)?

Comment: Not especially, I'm just working on Digital Communication, and I am trying to implement a full Communication Channel. That's why I'm wondering if every tap must be add or multiply at the receiver.